# Starring Samurais - Several Scribbled Short Stories

Tags: word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, anagram, acrostic

Flipping through my notebook, I found several stories I scribbled. What do they mean?

- First one

  > Samurai nagging, "Elixir agent, typewriter iamb, ultraviolet emitters..."
- Second one

  > Grenadier always shoots Evenki @Zulu range.
- Third one

  > Woo reedbuck in Gandhi opposition.
- Fourth one

  > Laura! Win Conor, ingenious ichthyosaurus
- Fifth one

  > Sec! Alexander, cause street rearrange tuba record!
- Sixth one

  > Career era: thou reverse folio - lead entrepreneur!
- Seventh one

  > Rousseau & Lovelace, roar "Ivanov", ever!

**HINTS**

Usefulness level 0:

> ```
> A close look at the correct clues so far will give you some hints on what you need
> ```

Usefulness level 1:

> There is more to the puzzle, even after ending up with pairs of words... Answer is a WORD...

**EDIT**: Sorry, how on earth can I miss out one of the stories!!

Comment: Hm, I've gotten the clear first step but haven't been able to figure out what to do with the results of it...

Comment: Very nice-looking puzzle!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The method:

> I built upon Deusovi's answer which identified that taking the first and last letter of each word produced two word phrases, and the fact that there was an anagram tag.  I then took each two word phrase and found a synonymous two word phrase where the two words were anagrams of each other.

First one:

> SINGER ATTRIBUTES = ARTIST TRAITS (from Stiv in comments)

Second one:

> GRASS SEIZURE = NAPIER RAPINE (from Omega Krypton on comments)

Third one:

> WORKING ION = ACTION CATION (from Deusovi in comments)

Fourth one:

> LAWN CRISIS = GARDEN DANGER

Fifth one:

> SCARCEST RETARD = RAREST ARREST

Sixth one:

> CREATURE FOLDER = ANIMAL MANILA

Seventh one:

> RULER RIVER = MASTER STREAM

Final solution:

> As PilsNot3 pointed out, if you take the first letter of each answer, it spells out **ANAGRAM**.

Comment: Pretty sure you're looking for rot13(NEGVFG GENVGF - NGGEVOHGRF vf cyheny va gur chmmyr)

Comment: @Stiv Thanks, I missed the plural.  The strange thing is, that was the first one I solved to lead me to the "pattern" but it turns out it was totally wrong (yet still "right")!

Comment: No worries - I've got a few favours to repay you! ;)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Does .5 mean my original answer was right for the first one?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton with my edits, am I at 5/7?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I could use a hint, I'm out of ideas at this point.

Comment: Looks like all of them are six letters - maybe ACTION CATION for 3? (but I hope not...)

Comment: @Deusovi I think you are right about the 6 letters, but I'm still out of ideas!

Comment: @deusovi why not?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Because "action" is a noun and "working" is a verb. Also, "ion" synonymizing "cation" would be a bit weird because that's where the second half comes from. it would be like synonymizing "blueberry" with "berry" - it would just be slightly strange, since it's really just the same word but with more detail.

Comment: @deus I'd admit the second one is a bit weird, but working can also be noun. they are synonymous, according to Google at least

Comment: @OmegaKrypton new guesses, any progress?

Comment: six out of seven now!

Comment: still same result after latest edit...

Comment: I think I see something that might help you figure out the second one... rot13(vs lbh gnxr gur svefg yrggref bs rnpu cuenfr, lbh trg N?NTENZ, juvpu vf nyzbfg pregnvayl fhccbfrq gb or NANTENZ, fb gur frpbaq cuenfr fubhyq fgneg jvgu na A). Haven't a clue as to what it could be, unfortunately

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Any progress in my last edit? If not, I think I will need another hint because I've exhaused all my "6 letter starting with N" anagrams

Comment: @JS1 final solution is correct, but not the clue. its rot13(ancvre encvar)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I had never heard of either word, but it does make sense now that I've looked them both up!

Answer (score 6):

## Partial Answer (first step figured out, vague thoughts on the second step)

If you

> read the first and last letters of each word

you get

> several two-word phrases: SINGER ATTRIBUTE, GRASS SEIZURE, WORKING ION, SCARCEST RETARD, CREATURE FOLDER, RULER RIVER

I'm not sure what to do next, though: it seems likely that we need to

> replace words with synonyms, so the two in each pair then have some sort of wordplay pattern... thing.
>
>  SINGER ATTRIBUTE could turn into TRAITOR / TRAIT (using "singer" in the sense of "informant"), but there are better words for that first synonym and the pattern doesn't seem to work for the others.
>
>  WORKING ION could change into ON ION, which has two patterns it might fit (making a word together, or one being the other plus a letter). But once again, neither of these patterns seems to extend to the rest of the phrases.

Comment: I tried to make something of rot13(NAVZNY naq YNZVAN) but no success there. I also wondered briefly about rot13(TENFF naq TENO, creuncf zrqvngrq ol TENẞ) but that seems obviously useless too.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps we could have a rot13(FAVGPU FANGPU) but I'm not seeing good candidates for the others.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan rot13(YRNFG ORNFG) maybe?

Comment: Those aren't from the same pair. (In case it's not clear, my informant isn't the same as yours.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Ah, right. (I had noticed that one also being a potential informant, but had forgotten.) I agree that keeping the pairs the same is the natural thing to do.

Comment: Since there's an anagram tag, is there rot13(nalguvat va gur snpg gung ERGNEQ vf bar yrggre njnl sebz na nantenz bs FPNEPRFG (ENERFG)?)

Comment: Ooh, didn't see the anagram tag!

Comment: @Stiv Yeah, I was looking at that. (But I also missed the tag!)

Comment: There's also rot13(GHEA naq GHEPBNG) but no anagramming there.